# Hyperbolic links

Tags: gt.geometric-topology

Let $L\subset L'\in S^3$ be two links such that $L$ has one less number of components than $L'$. Further, $L$ is hyperbolic. Under what conditions is the link $L'$ hyperbolic. To be more specific $L, L'$ are shown in [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbTGW.png).

Comment: better embed the image in the post?

Comment: The way you drew the image, I think, you can most certainly create some incompressible torus.

Comment: As it seems, if it is linked with the rest of the picture, then it cannot create any non-trivial sphere. So if it doesn't create any incompressible torus, then it will be a hyperbolic link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not enough information in your picture to give a definitive answer.  If you have more details about the link $L$ then an answer will probably factor through Thurston's characterisation of hyperbolic links.  [Purcell's book](http://users.monash.edu/~jpurcell/hypknottheory.html) is an introduction to the subject, and the second half of Theorem 8.17 therein is the precise statement you need.

Comment: Is it possible to say L' is hyperbolic or not given L is hyperbolic and a ribbon link? Again links L and L' are related as shown in the figure in the original question. Also, I know L is hyperbolic based on the fact that it is arborescent. Thank you!

Comment: No.  It is not possible to deduce hyperbolicity of L' from properties of L.  For, pull a bight out of L, tie a knot in the bight (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bight_(knot)#In_the_bight), and then use the green component (as in your figure) to link the bight to the rest of L. Then L' will be toroidal.